# Find the limit of the sequence $\frac{10}{n^2}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I really want to *understand* how to do these problems so that I can do them by myself. Please help me work out this one: Find the limit of the sequence defined by $$a_n= \frac{10}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$  Please set up the problem and show work.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: ok. I am taking AM3 at my high school. I understand the basics of how series work and using sigma without a calculator to find their sums. i do not know how to find the converging limimt since there is an n instead of a number there.Help please?

Comment: i tried to use a1/1-r but obviously that appears wrong to me

Comment: @Sofia I need to edit your question. Could you tell me if my interpretation of your formula is correct? $$a_n=\frac{10}{n^2[n(n+1)/2]}$$?

Comment: yes i believe that is correct

Comment: Are you asking about $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}a_n$?

Comment: @Morgan O OP has verified my interpretation of her formula. Could you please re-edit. Thanks!

Comment: jimmy: the first one i think. there is no sigma in the problem.... but there are sigmas in the next 3 problems

Comment: If it's the first one, I think Morgan's initial interpretation of the formula would be the correct one. With the formula as it stands, the answer to the "first one" is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned about the limit of the sequence, i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$, then consider what happens to $a_n = \dfrac{10}{n^2 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}} = \dfrac{20}{n^3(n+1)}$ as $n \to \infty$. The denominator gets arbitrarily large while the numerator is constant. What does that tell you about $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{20}{n^3(n+1)}$?

---

Now that you have edited your question to say $a_n = \dfrac{10}{n^2}*\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$, lets simplify the expression as follows: $a_n = \dfrac{10}{n^2} \cdot \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = \dfrac{10n(n+1)}{2n^2} = \dfrac{5(n+1)}{n} = 5\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$.

Now what happens to this expression when $n$ gets really big?

Comment: well acoording to how its written on my paper you are supposed to work out n(n+1)/2 then multiply THE WHOLE THING times 10/n^2 in your formula only the denominator is multiplied by the n(n+1)/2. i think that is wrong... or I could be wrong

Comment: What I wrote is the correct simplification based on the formula as currently written in the question. I multiplied the numerator and denominator by $2$ and then combined the $n^2$ and $n(n+1)$. If that formula is written incorrectly, then you should correct it so we can answer the question written on your paper.

Comment: someone edited my question

Comment: Then, you should edit your question so that the correct expression is there.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Sofia/Downloads/CodeCogsEqn%20(1).gif

Comment: never mind my equation didnt work .

Comment: Sofia, is it $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \frac{10}{n^2}$$?

Comment: yes!!!!!!! and i also fixed it now on my original question :) sorry, i am not very good with computers.

Comment: So how do you find the converging limit?

Comment: I simplified the expression to $a_n = 5(1+\frac{1}{n})$. Can you tell what happens to this expression for large values of $n$? Start by considering what happens to $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: so if n was 1 the answer would be 10 but if n was 100 then the answer would be 25.25 ...so 1/n would decrease but the actual annswer would increaese

Comment: For $n = 100$ you get $5(1+\frac{1}{100}) = 5(1+0.01) = 5.05$.

Comment: oh wait a minute...oh i was wrong -_- yep..... so how can u tell what number its converging to (although it will be smaller than 10 i understand)

Answer (score 1):

The best trick here when you have a limit where $n$ goes to $\infty$ is to just look at the biggest exponent over n, and keep that expression and divide with it both the numerator and the denominator, in our case we have:

$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \cdot \frac{10}{n^2}=\frac{10n^2+10n}{2n^2}$. So the biggest expression here in dependence of $n$ is $n^2$, so you just divide as described in the first sentence and you will have the result:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{10n^2+10n}{2n^2}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{10+10/n}{2}}=\frac{10+\lim_{n\to \infty}{10/n}}{2}=\frac{10}{2}=5$.